# Summarizing a list of xarray dataarray

Tags: python, list, sum, python-xarray

I have a list of multiple dataarray with same dimensions in name and size, I want to sum all of dataarrays and create a single dataarray with the same dimensions of dataarrays, what is the best way for do it?

```
[<xarray.DataArray (latitude: 501, longitude: 894)>
 array(..., dtype=float32)
 Coordinates:
   * longitude  (longitude) float64 49.8 49.81 49.81 49.82 ... 56.98 56.99 57.0
   * latitude   (latitude) float64 27.0 27.01 27.02 27.03 ... 31.98 31.99 32.0
     year       int64 2000,
.......
.......
 <xarray.DataArray (latitude: 501, longitude: 894)>
 array(..., dtype=float32)
 Coordinates:
   * longitude  (longitude) float64 49.8 49.81 49.81 49.82 ... 56.98 56.99 57.0
   * latitude   (latitude) float64 27.0 27.01 27.02 27.03 ... 31.98 31.99 32.0
     year       int64 2020]
```

Comment: By 'sum' do you mean you want to add the arrays element-wise, or do you wish to compute the sum of all elements in the array? Both are trivial. You compute the sum with `.sum()` (no surprise there) and you can compute an array with an element-wise sum for `a` and `b` with `a + b`. How someone can come to SO and ask a question like this without trying `.sum()` and `+` first blows my mind. Here's hoping I misunderstood the question.

Comment: @Grismar, I edited my question. I want to add the arrays element-wise and create a new dataarray with the same dimensions of dataarrays.

Comment: So, did you try `result = xrs[0]; for xr in xrs[1:]: result += xr`? If that's not what you need, can you describe the actual problem? (by the way, that's just one way to loop over a list and add up its elements, if that's what you needed, the question isn't really about `xarray` at all, it's about "how do I sum a list in Python"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can add two xarrays `a` and `b` elementwise with a simple `a + b` and you say you have a list of xarrays all with identical dimensions (let's call it `xrs`), then this is how you'd add all of them:

```
result = xrs[0]
for xr in xrs[1:]:
    result += xr
```

By the way, that's not specific to `xarray` at all. If you have a list of integers `xs` and you want to add all of them:

```
result = xrs[0]
for xr in xrs[1:]:
    result += xr
```

And as long as the addition operators are appropriately defined, `sum(xs)` would work just as well. And it does for `xarray`:

```
result = sum(xrs)
```